# Text/call on computer through phone

Tags: android, mobile, windows-10, phone

Is there any software that would allow me to connect my mobile phone to my laptop where I could text or call through my computer? My requirements are,

- App runs on Andriod OS
- Software runs on Windows 10
- Connection between computer and phone uses either USB, Wi-Fi, or Bluetooth

Comment: I just have to ask....Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Remote Phone Call before? It allows you to call phones and send/recieve sms right from your computer. It meets your requirements of running on Windows 10 and Android.

## [Remote Phone Call](http://www.justremotephone.com/)

> #### The remote control for your Android phone
>
> Remote Phone Call connects your Android phone with your Microsoft
> Windows PC. You can easily dial numbers, answer and end calls and
> write SMS messages. All from your desktop and also directly from
> Microsoft Outlook...
>
> ### Features of PC client
>
> - Dial numbers (PC2DIAL)
> - Write SMS messages (PC2SMS)
> - Add-in for Outlook, Word and Excel
> - Accept and end calls
> - View and search phone contacts
> - View call and SMS history
> - .NET/VBA API for own integrations
>
> ### Features of phone service
>
> - Auto start with WiFi and Bluetooth
> - Show connection status
> - Includes the PC client setup
>
> [image: Remote Phone Call]